# bit(8) vs tinyint

Tags: mysql, database

In the eyes of the storage engine, is there any difference at all between `bit(8)` and `tinyint`?

or `bit(16)` vs `smallint`?

or `bit(24)` vs `mediumint`?

or `bit(32)` vs `int`?

What I want to know is that are they synonymous and the engine treats one like the other?

Answer (score 1):

First off: I don't have any idea of the internals of how the individual engines would treat bit fields when trying to do queries.  I would be curious if it would be faster to index or query those two column types.

From a raw storage standpoint, these are the [storage requirements for numeric types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html):

- TINYINT  = 1 byte
- SMALLINT = 2 bytes
- MEDIUMINT = 3 bytes
- INT, INTEGER = 4
  bytes
- BIGINT = 8 bytes
- FLOAT(p) = 4 
  bytes if 0 <= p <= 24, 8 bytes if 25
  <= p <= 53 FLOAT = 4 bytes
- DOUBLE
  [PRECISION], REAL = 8 bytes
- DECIMAL(M,D), NUMERIC(M,D) = Varies;
  see following discussion
- BIT(M) =
  approximately (M+7)/8 bytes

Unless you're using NDBCluster storage engine which requires 4 bytes per storage record. (unless you have multiple bit types which will compact into that 4 byte minimum)

Edit:

According to [this page on numeric types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) tinyint(1) and bit were synonymous before version 5.0.3 for myISAM and 5.0.5 for MEMORY, InnoDB, BDB, and NDBCLUSTER.  This would imply they are no longer.

Comment: whether the engine will treat them IDENTICALLY internally, while doing storage / inserts / edits / deletes / etc / etc. in other words using one is IDENTICAL to using the other.. or not?

Comment: The docs say they are not, but it does not specify what specifically the difference is.